# Marker Annotation vs Marker Interface

Tags: java, interface, annotations

While reading about Marker interfaces I stumbled upon the following site : [Item 37: Use marker interfaces to define types](http://jtechies.blogspot.in/2012/07/item-37-use-marker-interfaces-to-define.html)

Here, according to Joshua Bloch there are two advantages of Marker interfaces over the Marker annotations.

> 1. Marker interfaces define a type that is implemented by instances of
>      the marked class; marker annotations do not. The existence of this
>      type allows you to catch errors at compile time that you couldn’t
>      catch until runtime if you used a marker annotation.
> 2. Another advantage of marker interfaces over marker annotations is
>      that they can be targeted more precisely. If an annotation type is
>      declared with target `ElementType.TYPE`, it can be applied to any
>      class or interface. Suppose you have a marker that is applicable
>      only to implementations of a particular interface. If you define it
>      as a marker interface, you can have it extend the sole interface to
>      which it is applicable, guaranteeing that all marked types are also
>      subtypes of the sole interface to which it is applicable.

OK, First point is understood but I'm not sure if I understand the 2nd point correctly:

> If an annotation type is declared with target `ElementType.TYPE`, it can be applied to any class or interface.

Likewise, if I have a marker interface then that too can be applied to any class or interface. Isn't it saying the same thing about marker annotations and marker interfaces? **How can a marker interface be targeted more precisely?**

The 2nd point also mentions that:

> you can have [the Marker Interface] extend the sole interface to which it is applicable, guaranteeing that all marked types are also subtypes of the sole interface to which it is applicable.

**Can't you also achieve this with annotations, by using the `@Inherited` meta-annotation**?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it a bit easier to understand. If I've change too much you can of course change it back.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **How can a marker interface be targeted more precisely?**

You are correct that both could be applied to any type. By "targeted more precisely" the author means that you can add additional restrictions to which specific types a marker interface can be applied to. It is not possible to add the same precise restrictions to annotations: If an annotation is restricted to `ElementType.TYPE`, then it can always be applied to all types.

The other part of the 2nd point goes into details how you can add those restrictions. If you have a marker interface, you can let it extend another interface (which the author calls the *sole interface*) like this:

```
interface Marker extends Foo { }
```

The marker can now only be applied to types which implement `Foo`.

> **Can't you also achieve this with annotations, by using the `@Inherited` meta-annotation**?

No, the `@Inherited` meta-annotation only means that any subtype of an annotated class will be treated as if it also had the same annotation. It does not impose any restrictions to which types the annotation can be applied to.

Comment: @kapep:    Is the author - Joshua Bloch trying to say that annotations cannot be inherited?

Comment: @akshayrajkore I edited the question and tried to make my answer more clear. Is it better to understand now?

Comment: IMO you can get similar behaviour if you need with annotations: just add @Foo on interface Foo. You can mark interfaces by annotation, but not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the sole interface thing.   This explains how marker interfaces can be made more restrictive (precisely was a bit confusing from the book though)

Answer (score 1):

For example, an annotation whose type is meta-annotated with @Target(ElementType.FIELD) may only be written as a modifier for a field declaration.

The constant TYPE_USE corresponds to the 15 type contexts in JLS 4.11, as well as to two declaration contexts: type declarations (including annotation type declarations) and type parameter declarations.

For example, an annotation whose type is meta-annotated with @Target (ElementType.TYPE_USE) may be written on the type of a field (or within the type of the field, if it is a nested, parameterized, or array type), and may also appear as a modifier for, say, a class declaration.

that may provide you with a conclusion over this.