# JAVA - Why annotation is better than marker interface?

Tags: java, annotations, marker-interfaces

I have read that since annotations are introduced, developers prefer to use them over marker interface, why??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080547/1553851

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26271786/1553851